# tf.io.decode_raw return tensor how to make it bytes or string

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm struggling with this for a while. I searched stack and check tf2
doc a bunch of times. There is one solution indicated, but
I don't understand why my solution doesn't work.

In my case, I store a binary string (i.e., bytes) in tfrecords.
if I iterate over dataset via as_numpy_list or directly call numpy()
on each item, I can get back binary string.
while iterating the dataset, it does work.

I'm not sure what exactly map() passes to test_callback.
I see doesn't have a method nor property numpy, and the same about type
tf.io.decode_raw return. (it is Tensor, but it has no numpy as well)

Essentially I need to take a binary string, parse it via my
x = decoder.FromString(y) and then pass it my encoder
that will transform x binary string to tensor.

```
def test_callback(example_proto):

    # I tried to figure out. can I use bytes?decode 
    # directly and what is the most optimal solution.

    parsed_features = tf.io.decode_raw(example_proto, out_type=tf.uint8)
    # tf.io.decoder returns tensor with N bytes.

    x = creator.FromString(parsed_features.numpy)
    encoded_seq = midi_encoder.encode(x)
    return encoded_seq

raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=["main.tfrecord"])
raw_dataset = raw_dataset.map(test_callback)
```

Thank you, folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution but I would love to see more suggestions.

```
def test_callback(example_proto):
    from_string = creator.FromString(example_proto.numpy())
    encoded_seq = encoder.encoder(from_string)
    return encoded_seq

raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=["main.tfrecord"])
raw_dataset = raw_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(test_callback, [x], [tf.int64]))
```

My understanding that tf.py_function has a penalty on performance.

Thank you